# more than 20 users on wireless and connection intermittently drops

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

There are about 25 users connected to the wireless network. Connection intermittently drops in a day. I have tried forcing in my ISP DNS. It seems that there are lesser disconnection but I cannot afford this intermittent disconnection. I need my wireless connection to be stable.

I am using a Aztech modem, not using any Access Point.

Is there any solution to solve this problem?

Comment: 25 users on wireless... and they are all in the same room? If you don't have other access point, and only have 1 Aztech Modem (which is your wireless access point) I can imagine people will be walking away too far from the wireless AP and their connection dropped off (due to distance, and also traffic). You may want to consider having more than 1 access points to distribute the load.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suspect the modem can not handle that many wireless users.  You will most likely need to move to a business class (or higher) wireless access point to accommodate heavy usage from that many wireless devices.

Comment: Thanks for that. Do you know what brand of modem that able to support many wireless users? @Keltari

Comment: those type of routers are normally called high powered routers, but I only know about Ubiquity, not sure if you can get those in your area

Comment: keep the modem, dont use it for wireless.  connect another WAP like the Cisco RV series, or equivalents, should be what you are looking for.